# NSURL returning nil When Calling an API

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to call an API and bring back menu items. My string seems to contain data because when I put it into a browser, I'm getting JSON.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/subway?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

My "urlString" contains a lot of information, but when I put a breakpoint on the NSURL object, it says it returns "nil".

EDIT: Removed spaces however the error persists.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];


NSData *ResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];



NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:ResponseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
itemName = dataDictionary[@"item_name"];

NSLog(@"%@", itemName);
```

EDIT: Added request code

Comment: you have a space in the url after the question mark

Comment: 1) Get rid of any spaces in the URL string. 2) Put the breakpoint on the line after `NSURL *url = ...`.

Comment: @videoperson why don't you use any framework for network? AFNetwroking will fit your needs.

Comment: I guess I could use one, but for now I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work with the method I'm currently using

Comment: What error? Instead of passing `nil` to the `error` parameter, why don't you actually make use of the `error` parameter and log it if `dataDictionary` is `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found something interesting about your url

You just forgot about string format. Every percent sign cry to you: 'I want to be replaced with something you gain to me!'

So, to prevent such behavior, you need to hide every percent with another percent: `%%`

```
-(void)doNSURLTestOne{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/subway?results=0%%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%%2Cbrand_name%%2Citem_id%%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSLog(@"is url nil? %@", url);
    NSLog(@"is urlString ok? %@", urlString);
}
```

But I prefer to use [AFNetworking](http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/) library for net part

**UPD**: better choice to use another clean `NSString` ( thanks @rmaddy )

```
-(void)doNSURLTestTwo{
    NSString *urlString = @"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/subway?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSLog(@"is url nil? %@", url);
    NSLog(@"is urlString ok? %@", urlString);
}
```

Comment: Instead of changing `%` to `%%`, why not just get rid of the needless `stringWithFormat`?